# It is with A as with B

Tags: usage, idiomatic-language

I saw the following [passage](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=WhkRAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA639&dq=%22constitute%20those%20societies%20where%20there%20are%20patented%20and%20privileged%22&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUwMTfnZvjAhUyGqYKHXQ8AEIQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22constitute%20those%20societies%20where%20there%20are%20patented%20and%20privileged%22&f=false) and am wondering whether "it is with A as with B" is current English. What is it used for? And what does "it" refer to?

> **It is with learning as with wealth**. A few cannot be immensely wealthy, but the many must be poor. One palace, and a thousand cabins—a few “nobles,” and a “numerous rabble,” constitute those societies where there are patented and privileged classes. So it is in learning sacred and common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context the words "It is..." are referring to **the big picture**<sup>[(Definition)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/big-bigger-picture)</sup>, how the world works at the highest or most general level.

The examples are of small sets -- the rich, the nobles, the sacred -- in contrast to large sets -- the poor, the commoners and the uneducated.

It is a claim made of the inevitability of such a condition, and how seeing it in these examples provides structure to other parts of life.

As a claim, it is useful in describing things, but *whether it is true* is for you to work out.

Comment: Is the pattern "It is with A as with B" natural in current English?

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, although it would be better to use the full version (*it is with learning as **it is** with wealth*) rather than omitting the second *it is*. An equally natural alternative would be *as [it is] with learning, so [it is] with wealth.* And *it* is a [dummy pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun).

Comment: Maybe the paraphrase should be "As [it is] with wealth, so [it is] with learning"? After all, the focus is learning.

Comment: Yes, that would be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is an everyday idiom - *it is with living-space as it is with money, no matter how much you have you never seem to have quite enough*.

The ***it*** is an 'expletive subject' - see the post on English Language & Users. [What does 'it' refer to in 'it's raining'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/what-does-it-refer-to-in-its-raining)